# Trigger an event after a user inputs data in an input field and presses enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I want to trigger an event after a user inputs data in an input field and presses <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
jQuery(document).one("PageComplete", function(e){
  // Do some stuff

  jQuery('#inputField').on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {  
       //do some stuff
       console.log("bbq chicken");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

For whatever reason the code never enters the `if` statement. However when I do this:

```
jQuery(document).one("PageComplete", function(e){
  // Do some stuff

  jQuery(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13 && jQuery('#inputField').length) {  
       //do some stuff
       console.log("bbq chicken");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

It enters the if statement but I noticed some bubbling (for every time I press the enter button the screen flashes twice) . How should I go about this and not have any bubbling occur?

Comment: Above you are saying it did not enter the If condition and in bottom you are saying it is entering the if condition but event bubbling is happening. Can you please explain the exact issue?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what is happening

Comment: You want to submit form on pressing enter on any fields in the form or some specific field?

Comment: I want to append the value of #inputField to a string after the user presses enter and then load that string into another function. So something like 
if (e.which ===13) { 
  var someStr = "blah blah" + jQuery('#inputField').val() + "blah blah";
  someFunction(someStr)
}

Comment: Check this out https://codepen.io/vicky86/pen/qBNopJv?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks. What is the "return" statement at the end for?

Comment: same result. It's not executing anything in the if statement

Comment: Please explain the steps which you have tried. I am able to execute that condition.